# How to play the sounds one by one the other within a specified BPM?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a small sequencer with my kids and struggle to find a solution on this.

I am using this library: https://github.com/alemangui/pizzicato

Our goal is to create little samples of their voice and have them playing one after the other(but not at the same time).

I wrote this code hoping to solve the problem but upon playing on "Play", all the samples play at the same time rather than 1 after the other...

```js
var sound = [];
this.samples.forEach((item, i) => {
  sound[i] = new Pizzicato.Sound(
    {
      source: "file",
      options: { path: item.sampleUrl },
    },
    () => {
      sound[i].play();
    }
  );
});
```

`this.samples` is just an array with the files(`wav`) URLs.

Our ultimate goal is to be able to play the files with a set BPM, ie: *120BPM*(Beat per minute).
I really thought it would have been a lot easier :-)

If you have a clever idea to solve this, you are welcome to demonstrate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback you pass while initializing the `Pizzicato.Sound` class is run immediately when the sound is ready to play.

So it's best to get all the sounds, pick one sound, play it and listen for it's [`end event`](https://github.com/alemangui/pizzicato#sounds-events-end) and call the next sound.

```
const sounds = this.samples.map(item => new Pizzicato.Sound({
  source: 'file',
  options: { path: item.sampleUrl }
}));

playSound(0);

function playSound(i) {
  sounds[i].play();
  if (i < sounds.length) sound.on('end', _ => playSound(++i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try your code in a couple of days and update you:-)

Comment: Okay then... till then :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have abandoned the idea of using pizzicato, no possibility to change the pitch and no demo on how to sync to a BPM.....spent hours and hours trying to figure it out but gave up, trying the P5 js library now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh... okay, let me know if you need any help with that